# How to exactly compute $dh_p(w)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $v\in R^3$ be a unit vector and let $h:S\to R$, $\text{ }h(p)=v\cdot p$, $\text{ }p\in S$, be the height function, where the dot denotes the usual inner product in $R^3$. $\text{ }h(p)$ is the height of $p\in S$ relative to a plane normal to $v$ and passing through the origin of $R^3$. To compute $dh_p(w),$ $\text{ }w\in T_p(S)$, choose a differentiable curve $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to S$ with $\alpha(0)=p$, $\text{ }\alpha'(0)=w$.

This is the part that I don't quite understand:

Since $h(\alpha(t))=\alpha(t)\cdot v$, we obtain

$$dh_p(w)=\frac{d}{dt}h(\alpha(t))\lvert_{t=0}$$

How do we explicitly compute $dh_p(w)$ and end up getting $\frac{d}{dt}h(\alpha(t))\lvert_{t=0}$?

That is how can we go from $dh_p(w)$ to $\frac{d}{dt}h(\alpha(t))\lvert_{t=0}$?

I understand the basic ideas of the meaning of differentials but not exactly sure how to carry out the computation.

Some explanations are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which set is $S$? and $\frac{d}{dt}h(\alpha(t))\lvert_{t=0}=dh_{\alpha(0)}(\dot \alpha(0))=dh_p(w)$ by the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $S$ is the unit sphere (and using the chain rule):

$\frac{d}{dt}h(\alpha(t))\lvert_{t=0}=dh_{\alpha(0)}(\dot \alpha(0))=dh_p(w)$

We can take $\alpha(t)=p+tw$, so $dh_p(w)=\frac{d}{dt}(v\cdot \alpha(t))=v \cdot\alpha'(0)=v \cdot w$

Comment: Thank you. S is just a surface.